# What is the difference between "there is no" and "there is not"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "there is **no**" and "there is **not**" (the same question for "there are **no**" and "there are **not**"?

For example:

> There is **no** an apple on the table.

versus

> There is **not** an apple on the table.

Comment: The first example is just wrong (the *no an* part).

Comment: Thank you. I really didn't know that. What is the reason that "no" 'cancels' the article?

Comment: It is not definite. It is not indefinite. Because it (the apple) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example would be correct if you omit **an**.

If someone asked you to remove the apple lying on the table, you might reply:

> There is no apple on the table.

strongly emphasizing the absence of the apple

or, using your second example:

> There is not an apple on the table.

In practice, people would nearly always abbreviate that to:

> There isn't an apple on the table.

**There is no** is frequently used for universal statements, such as:

> There is no hope; there is no way; there is no chance/possibility

**There is not**, frequently abbreviated to **there isn't**

is generally used to make a simple negative statement or to deny a positive one.

> There isn't a bus until midday.

However, in many instances, you can use either construction.

Comment: Thank you. I really didn't know that. What is the reason that "no" 'cancels' the article?

Comment: @Archimedean_Point **No** used in this fashion is a way of saying **not any**. So to say:*There is no hope* is to say: *There is not any hope*. The article would not fit into such a construction.